# Defective clock questions - Watch gaining 3 minutes every hour

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

An analog watch gains 3 minutes every hour.  If it is set right at 11 a.m. on February 21st, 2012 when will the hour hand of this defective watch and a correct watch be at the same position ?

---

**My attempt :-**

My understanding regarding the gaining of time is as follows :-

Correct watch----Defective watch

11 am--------------11 am

12 pm--------------12:03 pm

1 pm--------------1:06 pm

2 pm--------------2:09 pm

and so on

I assumed that t hrs after 11 a.m. in the normal clock , both the clocks show the same time

so t hrs in normal clock will be equivalent to $t+\frac{3t}{60}$ hrs

I am stuck at this point on what further equation to make to solve for t

Alternative method :- Why cant we do as follows as well :- for every 60 minutes elapsed on normal clock, time elapsed on defective clock= 63 minutes, so after LCM(60,63) minutes = 1260 minutes , both should show the same time ? why is this not acceptable ?

Edit :- if possible please explain me using the equations only from what I have made, how shall I find "t" from there ?

---

I have no clue what the official solution has done by simply calculating :-

$\frac{12*60 min}{3 min/hr}$=240 hours= 10 days

Comment: Does the clock distinguish between 11:00 a.m. and 11:00 p.m. ?

Comment: it shouldnt as the clock is analog

Comment: If not , the gain must be $12$ hours which is $720$ minutes for which the clock needs $240$ hours.

Comment: how did you come up with the gain to equal 12 hours or 720 minutes ?

Comment: Well, then the clock shows the correct time again :)

Comment: I am still not able to understand it Peter :( , I am not able to think how focussing on gain is giving us the time when the correct clock and defective clock show same time , could you please write an answer explaining it a bit more

Comment: Let's be sure what "hour hand" means.  Is it the short one that completes a circuit in 12 hours or the long one which completes a circuit in 1 hour?  For mean, it is the first of those.  Also do the hands move smoothly or click from position to position.  For the 12 hour case and smooth movement then it is what Peter says,

Comment: Why cant we do as follows :- for every 60 minutes elapsed on normal clock, time elapsed on defective clock= 63 minutes, so after LCM(60,63) minutes = 1260 minutes , both should show the same time ? why is this not acceptable ?

Comment: @VasuGupta the LCM would only tell us that both the actual hand and the imaginary correct hand moved 1260 minutes in a whole number of hours, but not necessarily in the **same** whole number of hours.  The LCM in other words is not really giving you a time per se (even though its in minutes), its giving you a distance on the face of the clock, which takes a different amount of time for the actual hand to reach compared to the correct hand.

Comment: The "faster" one gains 3 min every hour, that means 20*2=60 i.e. it gains an hour every 20 hours. So, to coincide again, it needs 12 "gains" to reach the initial position, that means 12*20=240.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA why does it need 12 gains to coinicde ? I do not understand that

Comment: Because the full circle is made of 12 hours and thus it has to perform 12 gains.

Answer (score 2):

The actual position of the hour hand is running away from the correct position at a rate of $3$ minutes per hour.  The actual position needs to do a complete "lap" of $12\cdot 60$ minutes on the face of the watch, so that's the total "distance" it needs to cover, where distance is interpreted as minutes on the watch relative to the correct hour hand.  So now the official solution is just using the formula $$\text{time}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{rate}} = \frac{12\cdot 60\text{ minutes on clock}}{3\text{ (minutes on clock)/hour}} = 240 \text{ hours}\text{.}$$

Comment: How is the correct position (normal clock's hour hand) running faster ?  The hour hand of defective clock is running 3 minutes more per hour than the correct position, right ?

Comment: Yeah I got them backwards, just edited it to fix, the argument works exactly the same otherwise.

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted, did I get something wrong?

Comment: 3 minutes on clock / hour is the relative speed of the minute hands of correct and defective clock right ?

Comment: No, the speed measured is in (clock minutes/hour), but the hand is the hour hand

Comment: when minute hand of normal clock covers 60 minutes in an hour , the minute hand of broken clock covers 63 minutes .  So why are the relative speeds not for minute hand ? that is 3 minutes/hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148019/discussion-between-m-w-and-vasu-gupta).